# iOS swift - UICollectionView scrollToItem at scrollPosition of the item

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

How is it possible to scroll to item and set the horizontal `collectionView` `UICollectionView.ScrollPosition` to the exact position of the item (not the `.right, .left` etc) and at the same time enable the scroll to the user? I tried this:

```
var selectedLineIdexPath: IndexPath? {
        
        didSet {
            
            if let index = self.selectedLineIdexPath {
                
                self.linesCollectionView.scrollToItem(at:index, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
            }
        }
    }
```

Where the selectedIndexPath is set on the:

```
final func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

depending on the value of my data.

The result is that the collectionView scroll to this item but when I try to select fetch and select another one its automatically scroll to the center.

Comment: What do you mean by exact position of the item (not the .right, .left)? The position is where the `item` is displayed inside the `collectionView`.

Comment: @PGDev for example if I have 10 items and only 5 that are displayed and I want to scroll automatically to the 8 item, the collectionView scrolls correctly but when I try to reselect manually another one, the collectionView scroll it self to the center

Comment: @NeAS, what happens in the `collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)` method of your collection view's delegate? Does it by chance modify your `selectedLineIdexPath` property, thus causing the collection view to scroll?